# MS word special character when pasted on html textbox work fine on staging server but fail on production server

Tags: html, encoding, ms-word, character

We are facing this on production when we copy the below text

> Testing’s please, “ignore” 3

on the text box. It is saved as below

> Testingâ??s please, â??ignoreâ?� 3

This works fine on staging servers but the problem occurs on production server.

Comment: What you're describing is not a server issue but a client issue. Please provide more details on how you manipulate the value from the textbox. Are you sending it to the server? Are you saving it in a database?

Comment: yes, the value when copied from MS Word and pasted in a textbox is sent from the chrome browser to the Server and then saved in database. This process works fine when request is made on staging servers but this error occurs on production server only.

Comment: Still not sure how you're sending the value to the server. Is the value broken on the text field or on the database?

Comment: The value when copied from MS word say [Testing’s please, “ignore” 3] is pasted into textbox is not broken. when submitted and the same value is saved in database and list of saved values  are returned. This value is then displayed as [Testingâ??s please, â??ignoreâ?� 3].

Comment: What is the collation that you use in the database? Is it UTF-8? Also, you should be escaping the value when saving it to the DB. With PHP you could try "mysqli_real_escape_string". What is your server-side language?